# How do I store and add up the output/Update the chart

Tags: java, windows, bluej

I am just new to Java.I want to create a table which updates on input.If the input is between 1-20 the answer should be 5.If 21-40 the answer should be 10.
So I will take an example like this:
Input 1: 7====Answer=5
Input 2: 23====Answer=10
So on entering the first input I want the output as 5.But I want the output as 15(Sum of 1st and 2nd output) after entering them both.Is there any way.Here is a code I created to assign values

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

class  Vedant
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter input");
            Scanner inputa=new Scanner(System.in);
            int b=inputa.nextInt();
            if(b > 0 && b < 20);
            int a=5;
            {
                System.out.println("Answer ="+a);
            }
            if(b<0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
}
}
```

Please help me guys ..I am a beginner and don't know much about Java

Answer (score -1):

when you use `if()` statement with `;` like `if();` it will be always consider as `if(true)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class  Vedant {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter input");
        Scanner inputa=new Scanner(System.in);
        int b=inputa.nextInt();
        if(b > 0 && b =< 20)
        {
            System.out.println("Answer = 5");
        }
        else if(b > 21 && b < 40)
        {
            System.out.println("Answer = 10");
        }
        if(b<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup but I tried putting else there..It said else without if error so I just used if..I will try this code

Comment: @Vedant you can use `if()` instead of `else if()`

Comment: I am getting illegal start of expression if I don't put semicolon after if statement at the end.Also I want those 5 & 10 as values and not texts cuz I want to add them later

Comment: `if(condition)` or `else if(condition)` or `else()` with `else` no condition

Comment: Yup.Is this code right: https://pastebin.com/iDMM11f3 ..So what I basically want to do is add up the values everytime I input something.Like I said in the question

Comment: i did not said that your code won't compile, but in **java** `if();` is similar to `if(true)`

Comment: Ohh k get it.But how do I make the program so that it will add up every time I input?

Comment: @Vedant i cannot understand you

Comment: Yea no prob..See suppose I will enter 2 inputs.If the input is between 1-20 the output will be 5.I will assign one more range in which if the input is between 20-40 the output will be 10.So In first input suppose I enter 7 the output should be 5.In second input I put 27 the output will be 10 right.I want the program to add up the two outputs so that the total will be 15.But I won't enter both the inputs at the same time

Comment: Get it bro?I really need an idea

Comment: @Vedant can you at least write down algorithmically ?

Comment: Yeah this thing won't be perfect but you may get an Idea:Input:a,If 0<a<20 ,b=5,System.out.println("Answer"+b)..So next day I enter second input so it will be like:Input :c,If 0<c<20,d=5,e=b+d,System.out.println(e)...So like that I will keep on adding the inputs.Hope you get a rough idea

Comment: @Vedant if you want to keep previous values, in case of next day inputs you need to store previous values into database or file